# LinkedIn API: get current rate limit

Tags: linkedin-api, rate-limiting

Is there a way to get the current LinkedIn api rate limit ?
I see in my app page the data I'm looking for but I'd like to get it programmaticaly.

I see nothing in headers of each requests. 
Other API like facebook send a header 'x-app-usage' that helps me to reduce the frequency of my calls. Is there any equivalent ?

I've found on stackoverflow other posts that tell me what are the rates but I don't want to increment a counter by my side, I have other platforms that will use the same api tokens...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late but if somebody else search this:
Login to the [LinkedIn developer dashboard](https://www.linkedin.com/developers) select your app and go to the Analytics section. If you already make API call then you see limit for that resource.